# Detecting data boundaries in matlab

Tags: matlab, detection, boundary

Suppose vector A represents serial value taken from actigraphy of a rabbit.
And Vector T have corresponding time-stamp data.

At night, rabbit rarely moves (but not zero-move).
At morning, when rabbit awakens, it consistently moves.

In matlab, plot (T,A) draws activity graph of rabbit like below:
[image]

I want to detect boundary between 'sleeping state' and 'awaken state'.
Actual sleeping time is shown red check mark in graph below.
And awakening period is shown between yellow parenthesis.
[image]

Of course, I know detecting these boundary is largely heuristic process. 
The problem is, some activity segmentations during sleeping state.
If rabbit does not move, the problem is pretty easy.
But even sleeping, rabbit sometimes moves(shown in green check mark), so it's hard for me to filter out these data to detect between 'sleep stage' and 'awakening stage'.
Adjusting some filtering and detection threshold value, I think there should be some way to do these process.

I tried searching for 'boundary detection' or 'data segmentation', but I couldn't find any cues I could use.

Comment: I can't see what is special about those times you're showing. How are they determined. It looks like there are periods with less activity than those you have there. If that's the only place you have exactly zero movement for a small period of time, search for `find(~diff(A))`, or `t(~diff(A))`, to get the corresponding time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited my original question. Actually, there are few 'true zero' data. I want to filter out some chunks of 'sleeping but with some activity' signals, but can't find how.

Comment: one possible approach: get the "envelope" of your signal (at a lower sampling rate). Define a threshold (slightly above zero to not pick up the 'close to zero' noise). You will then have several "blocks" (above your threshold) of different width. Define a minimum width to consider the rabbit "awake" ... that's your interval. The other blocks are just the rabbit moving in his sleep.